# Problem with joining two tables on subquery condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables:

1)  et_pics - here information about employees:

- ob_no, int, key, e.g. 2020
- c_name, varchar, e.g. Dribbler D.E.
- e_post, varchar, e.g. Chairman

  SELECT * FROM et_pics:

> ob_no   | c_name        | e_post
>
> 2020    | Dribbler D.E. | Chairman

2)  et_vacations – here information about vacation is stored:

- ob_no, int, e.g. 666 e_pic, int, connection to pic.ob_no, e.g. 2020
- c_name, varchar, e.g. Vacation blah blah
- e_dateFrom, date, e.g. 2010-08-08 00:00:00.000
- e_dateTo, date, e.g 2010-08-09 00:00:00.000

  SELECT * FROM et_vacations vac returns

> ob_no | e_pic  |c_name    |  e_dateFrom                  |e_dateTo
>       |
>    777   |  2020  |Vacation blah blah |2010-08-08 00:00:00.000 | 2010-08-09 00:00:00.000 |
>
> 777   |  2020  |Vacation blah blah |2015-08-08 00:00:00.000 | 2015-08-09 00:00:00.000 |

What I need to do is to connect et_vacations to et_pics with conditions:

- the could be only one vacation record per person (seems to me
  max(e_dateTo));
- vacation record must be >= getDate() or null is
  displayed.

Can’t understand how to write right subquery – tried in this way, but no luck:

```
SELECT
    pics.c_name,
    pics.e_post,
vac.e_dateTo
FROM et_pics pics
INNER JOIN et_division div on pics.e_division = div.ob_no
INNER JOIN et_vacations vac on vac.e_pic = pics.ob_no
WHERE
    (pics.e_fireDate IS NULL OR pics.e_fireDate > getDate()) 
    AND vac.e_dateTo IN (
    SELECT MAX(vac.e_pic) from et_vacations vac
    GROUP BY vac.e_pic
    )
    ORDER BY pics.c_name;
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand.. can you post sample of expected results?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Or you could post tables and sample data at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What does "no luck" mean?   What is wrong with the results you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem needs a bit more definition around what is considered the date of the vacation (the beginning date?, the end date?) you are interested in but here is a start. Note I left the join to division in since you had it but you are not using the data in that table in any of the select field or where clauses.  Unless it is being used to reduce the number of people who are in the query because not everyone in et_pics is in et_division, then this join should be removed.

```
SELECT
    pics.c_name,
    pics.e_post,
vac.e_dateTo
FROM et_pics pics
INNER JOIN et_division div on pics.e_division = div.ob_no
INNER JOIN(select e_pic, max(e_dateTo) from  et_vacations group by e_pic )vac on vac.e_pic = pics.ob_no
WHERE
    (pics.e_fireDate IS NULL OR pics.e_fireDate > getDate()) 
       ORDER BY pics.c_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to output employees with nearest planed vacation(?). Then you should JOIN already prepared `et_vacations` table using LEFT JOIN in case of empty vacations records for some of employees:

```
WITH T_vac as 
(
  select et_vacations.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e_pic ORDER BY e_dateTo) as RowNum
  from et_vacations 
  where e_dateTo>=getDate()
)
SELECT
    pics.c_name,
    pics.e_post,
    vac. e_dateFrom,
    vac.e_dateTo
FROM et_pics pics
LEFT JOIN T_vac vac on (vac.e_pic = pics.ob_no) AND (vac.RowNum=1)
    ORDER BY pics.c_name;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94276/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I soleved by myself with CTE, but HLGEM was frist:

```
;WITH Vacations_nah AS 
(
    SELECT
        vac.e_pic,
        MAX(vac.e_dateTo) AS e_dateTo_2
    FROM et_vacations vac 
    WHERE e_dateTo >=getDate()
    GROUP BY vac.e_pic
)
SELECT  
    pics.c_name,
    pics.e_post,
    e_dateTo_2
FROM et_pics pics
    INNER JOIN et_division div on pics.e_division = div.ob_no 
    LEFT JOIN Vacations_nah nah on nah.e_pic = pics.ob_no
WHERE 
    (pics.e_fireDate IS NULL OR pics.e_fireDate > getDate())
    AND pics.c_visible=1
```